# anyone tried google translate api v2 (and got it working)?

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I've been experimenting with google translate api v2 but I couldn't get it working.

this is the current code i have: http://juzcode.com/z.html (just visit the page and view source)

I can use google translate api v1 though: http://juzcode.com/y.html

Does anyone know why google is rejecting my request in the page http://juzcode.com/z.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API v2 uses a different system for generating and validating keys, so you need to get a new key.  Go to http://code.google.com/apis/console/ and sign up for one.

If you want an easier way of testing this, you can go to the URL directly.  So if I go to https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de&key=(my key>), I get the following:

```
{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "Hallo Welt"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: heys cool now i can get the data directly from the browser, however when i try to access it through XHR it still rejects my request.

Comment: Looks like some kind of XSS problem. Try the JavaScript example on http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html, which doesn't use XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: is there a way to fix the problem in such a way that i can use XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Not sure you can.  It's going to be easiest just to do it the way you see it on that page, and you're more likely to be able to get help if you have any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/

I used their code before v1 was deprecated and I only had to update the query.translate.js file they provide and add one line of code to what I previously had: `$.translate.load('API-KEY');` and it worked perfectly!